# How can i find list of all files checked out by myself in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Since my TFS has lots of branches and folders, Can anyone help me to know how to find list of all files locked by myself and in which branch i have locked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given workspace, you can use tf status. If you want the list of pending changes for all workspaces, you would need to call tf status for each.

You may also find the [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm) useful for this.